# 404 Resource Not Found for Static Assets in Play App

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this configuration on my routes:

`GET     /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

I have some file in public folder 
`public/stylesheets/home.css`

when I try to get this file it returns

`curl localhost:9663/assets/stylesheets/home.css`

`404 Resource not found`

I've found the problem is this line in `build.sbt`

```
resourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "assets"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked with my **Play 2.7** App and it works.

The only difference I have is in the `route` file:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

There is a *deprecated* warning - but at least it works.

**After the question was updated:**

`resourceDirectory in Assets` defines where Play looks for the Assets.

By default Play looks in the `public` folder. With this line you have overwritten that to `app/assets` as the `sourceDirectory` is `app` in Play.

To solve your problem **just remove that line** or move your assets.

By the way this is the configuration that Play uses:

```
resourceDirectory in Assets := baseDirectory.value / "public"
```

Comment: so you have now a solution by removing `resourceDirectory in Assets := (sourceDirectory in Compile).value / "assets"` ?

Comment: I adjusted my answer